# Nao amarzena dados na fila

Tags: c, fila

No meu programa, preciso usar uma função de armazenamento de fila dentro de outra função, porem não consigo rodar, não armazena. troquei do DevC++ Para o CodeBlocks e aparece isso:

> "expected 'struct Fila' but argument is of type 'struct FILA *"

Segue a estrutura que contem a fila:

```
typedef struct Fila {
    int vetor[3][10];
    int tamanho[3];
} FILA;
```

Os protótipos das minhas funções:

```
void fLimpar(int a, struct Fila *Carro);
void fArmazenar(int a, struct Fila *Carro, int e);
int fRemover(int a, struct Fila *Carro);
int Menu(struct carros *carro, struct Fila *Carro);
```

E a implementação de duas dessas funções:

```
void fArmazenar(int a, struct Fila *Carro, int e) {

    // Armazena o elemento na próxima posição vaga.
    (*Carro).vetor[a][((*Carro).tamanho[a])] = e;
    printf("teste : ta com %d", (*Carro).vetor[a][(*Carro).tamanho[a]]);
    (*Carro).tamanho[a]++;
}

int fRemover(int a, struct Fila *Carro) {

    int e, i;

    // elemento a ser retornado é o primeiro da fila.
    e = (*Carro).vetor[a][0];

    // Move todos os elementos 1 posição para frente,
    // exceto o 1º (pois este será descartado).
    for (i = 1; i < (*Carro).tamanho[a]; i++) {
        (*Carro).vetor[a][i - 1] = (*Carro).vetor[a][i];
    }

    // diminui o tamanho em 1 porque o elemento do início da fila foi removido.
    (*Carro).tamanho[a]--;

    return e;
}
```

Um exemplo de como estou usando a estrutura dentro da minha função menu:

```
 if((*carro).estado[0] == 'V'){

    fArmazenar(1, &Carro, 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não pude rodar seu código, mas creio que o problema de compilação seja porque você criou uma `struct` e fez dela um "tipo", para variáveis, usando a definição `typedef`, porém, na hora de declarar uma variável com o tipo criado, você quis declará-la como uma simples estrutura.

Quando declaramos uma `struct` podemos observar a seguinte regra de declaração:

```
struct <identificador>
{
 <listagem dos tipos e membros>;
} <variavel>
```

onde:

`<identificador>` é o nome dado a struct, para poder identificar a estrutura que estamos criando;

`<variavel>` é a variável, propriamente dita, declarada;

Exemplo:

```
/*declaracao da estrutura*/
 struct ANIMAL
{
    int patas;
    char raca[10]; 
} gato // voce criou um variavel gato com a estrutura de um ANIMAL;
```

Ou podemos fazer dessa forma:

```
/*declaracao da estrutura*/
struct ANIMAL
{
    int patas;
    char raca[10]; 
} 

/*declaracao da variavel*/
struct ANIMAL gato; // voce criou um variavel gato com a estrutura de um ANIMAL;
```

Quando você faz de uma estrutura um tipo, usando o `typedef`, você faz dessa estrutura um tipo conhecido para seu programa, como se ela fosse um tipo primitivo (int, char, float), ou seja, no seu programa, a estrutura que você definiu como um tipo, usando `typedef`, agora é um tipo para variáveis. A estrutura, para uso do `typedef`, funciona dessa forma:

```
typedef < tipo > <nome_para_o_tipo>
```

onde:

`< tipo >` é o tipo que será "renomeado", podendo ser um tipo já existente (int, char, float, etc), ou um tipo complexo (structs, enuns, ect);

`<nome_para_o_tipo>` é o nome que você dará ao tipo;

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
/* Aqui, estamos dizendo que o tipo int também será conhecido, pelo o programa, como int32*/
typedef int int32;  // definição do tipo int32
int32 cont; // declaração da variável "cont" do tipo int32 (que na verdade é um int)
```

Para uma estrutura ficará assim:

```
/*Tranformando uma estrutura em um tipo*/
typedef < tipo >
{
 <listagem dos tipos e membros>;
} <nome_para_o_tipo>
```

Exemplo:

```
/*Aqui estamos tornando uma estrutura em um tipo complexo*/
typedef struct ANIMAIS 
{
    int patas;
    char raca[10]; 
} ANIMAL // estamos dizendo que a struct ANIMAIS será conhecida, no programa, como o tipo complexo ANIMAL;

ANIMAL gato; // criamos uma variável gato do tipo complexo ANIMAL. como a estrutura virou um tipo, não é necessário colocar o struct antes do ANIMAL.
```

Bom, sendo assim, acho que as correções a serem feitas em seu programa são conforme segue abaixo:

```
typedef struct Fila {
    int vetor[3][10];
    int tamanho[3];
} FILA;

void fLimpar(int a, FILA *Carro);
void fArmazenar(int a, FILA *Carro, int e);
int fRemover(int a, FILA *Carro);
int Menu(struct carros *carro,FILA *Carro);

void fArmazenar(int a, FILA *Carro, int e) {

    // Armazena o elemento na próxima posição vaga.
    (*Carro).vetor[a][((*Carro).tamanho[a])] = e;
    printf("teste : ta com %d", (*Carro).vetor[a][(*Carro).tamanho[a]]);
    (*Carro).tamanho[a]++;
}

int fRemover(int a, FILA *Carro) {

    int e, i;

    // elemento a ser retornado é o primeiro da fila.
    e = (*Carro).vetor[a][0];

    // Move todos os elementos 1 posição para frente,
    // exceto o 1º (pois este será descartado).
    for (i = 1; i < (*Carro).tamanho[a]; i++) {
        (*Carro).vetor[a][i - 1] = (*Carro).vetor[a][i];
    }

    // diminui o tamanho em 1 porque o elemento do início da fila foi removido.
    (*Carro).tamanho[a]--;

    return e;
}
```

Segue uns links para você encontrar mais detalhes referente a structs e typedef: [structs](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/Como-declarar-uma-struct-em-C.html) e [typedef](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/typedef-Como-declarar-seus-proprios-tipos-em-C.html)

Ou você pode declarar a estrutura sem o `typedef` e a variável `FILA`, desta forma, você não precisará alterar o restante do seu programa:

```
struct Fila {
   int vetor[3][10];
   int tamanho[3];
};
```

Outra coisa que você pode verificar é se a variável `Carro` , que você está passando por parâmetro para as funções `fArmazenar(int a, FILA *Carro, int e)` e  `fRemover(int a, FILA *Carro)`, é um valor ou um endereço. Esse erro, que o compilador está informando, é tipico desse tipo de erro. Você pode estar querendo passar um parâmetro por valor, porém, as funções estão esperando receber um parâmetro por referência (um endereço de memória).
 De qualquer forma, verifique isso, ou mande o restante do código, onde você chama essas funções para que possamos ver como você está declarando a variável Carro e como você está passando parâmetros para as funções.